# SQL (Teradata) Select data

Tags: sql, between, teradata

I have a questions related to SQL (teradata in particular).
I have to generate the report for 1 day.

How can I achieve it?

For example, in ms access, I can do

```
WHERE DT>=#2011-01-01# and DT<=#2011-0101#
```

What about big-guys? (SQL Server, not MS Access).

I know that it is possible to use

```
DT between '2011-09-01' and '2011-09-02'
```

But this method is not precise. How can I specify 1 day using ranged WHERE statement?

I apologize, I don't have the SQL access and I can't test it; therefore I am asking for professional advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BETWEEN` is range-inclusive, so this will do:

```
DT between '2011-09-01' and '2011-09-01'
```

And, yes, it is precise :)

Now, if your `DT` is a datetime field (not date field), then you must change your approach:

```
DT >= '2011-09-01' and DT < '2011-09-02'
```

Comment: My IT stating that it is not :-\ Can i use DT >= '2011-09-01' AND DT <= '2011-09-01' ?

Comment: Stating that is not precise? Based on what? Please define how a BETWEEN "is not precise" so we can better help.

Comment: "The BETWEEN operator is treated differently in different databases!" http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: You should know w3schools is not a very reliable source of knowledge. Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL)#BETWEEN
Also, you should look here as well: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Also, sharing my experience, I've worked with SQL Server, Oracle, Firebird, Informix, MS Access, MySQL, PostGreSQL (I might be forgetting some minor ones). **Absolutely NONE of them** has BETWEEN being exclusive ranges.

Answer (score 4):

Working with dates in Teradata can be a little tricky.

If DT is a "timestamp" field, you can simply convert it to a date and, because you are reporting for exactly one day, just test for equality.

Let's say you want to report on today, so pass in '03/20/2012':

```
-- Teradata: Select records where DT matches a certain day.
SELECT * -- etc...
WHERE CAST(DT as date) = TO_DATE('03/20/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

MS SQL is similar:

```
SELECT * from [webdb].[mediaguide].[fileDirectories]
WHERE CAST('03/20/2012' AS date) = CAST(DT AS date)
```

Technically I'd use parameterization for passing in the date, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

When selecting over a range (especially dates and timestamps), it's best to do lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive.  That is, you want things in the range `lb <= x < ub`.  In your case, this amounts to:

```
SELECT [list of columns]
FROM [table]
WHERE dt >= :startDate
AND dt < :endDate
```

(the `:variableName` is how I input host variables on my system.  You'll have to look up what it is on teradata.)
The strings you have listed for your between will work as-is - I think pretty much every major RDBMS recognizes *ISO formatting by default.

Comment: I am wondering if you are correct TRUE(<=) AND FALSE(<) return FALSE? How it supposed to work?

Comment: @Andrew - What?  Could you please explain a little more?  And booleans aren't really range-able - they can only be `true` or `false` (... I'm ignoring null for this, thank you very much).

Comment: DT<=2011-01-01 (TRUE) AND DT < 2011-01-01 (FALSE); this meanws that Second potion should be AND dt <= :endDate (to make it true and be included in the range)? Is that correct?

Comment: @Andrew - Ah, I see what you're getting at.  No, my answer is equivalent to the second portion of the one that Adrian posted; that is `:startDate` should be `'2011-09-01'` and `:endDate` should be `'2011-09-02'`, which would select all times for the day of `2011-09-01`.  Attempting to do upper-bound inclusive for timestamps is murder, because you have to muck with everything down to the microsecond/nanosecond level - go from start of day (usually trivial), add a day, and get less than that value, it's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be:

```
WHERE DT BETWEEN Date_X AND Date_X + 1
```

If you want to be explicitly

```
WHERE DT BETWEEN Date_X AND Date_X + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

You can always read Teradata Manual :)

[Teradata Manual on BETWEEN](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference%2FB035-1145-160K%2Fvey1472241096825.html%23wwID0E6OAK)

Following their manual, ***x BETWEEN y AND z*** == ***((x >= y) AND (x <=z))***